# I am not able to add web part for Task List, Issue Tracking in SharePoint Modern UI SIte pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, web-partmodern-w

I am able to add Document library and Simple generic list as a web part in Modern Site Pages. But failed to add Task and Issue tracking lists.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to activate some site feature or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has not implemented modern versions of these yet. So you have to go back to Classic to use them as web parts.